# Filtering WordPress API with Angular pipe?

Tags: wordpress, angular, typescript, wordpress-rest-api

Currently trying to use a custom pipe to filter my *ngFor list items to toggle posts with a comment status of opened or closed. Seem to have run into a snag on setting it up.

Code is as follows:

**app.component.html**

```
  <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option value="all" selected="selected">All</option>
    <option value="open">Open</option>
    <option value="closed">Closed</option>
  </select>

  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let post of posts | myPipe:commentStatus">
      <h1>{{ post.title.rendered }}</h1>
      comment status: {{ post.comment_status }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'rest-ang';

  posts = [];

  wpUrl = 'http://wprest.local/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';

  filterByComments= '';

  //postsTitle: any = {};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    return this.http.get(this.wpUrl)
      .subscribe(data => {
        for(let key in data){
          if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            this.posts.push(data[key]);
          }
        }
        console.log(data);
        //console.log(this.postsTitle);
      })
  }

  onChange(optionFromMenu:string) {
    if(optionFromMenu === 'all'){
      this.posts = this.posts;
    } 
    if(optionFromMenu === 'closed') {
      this.posts = this.posts.filter(data => {
        return this.posts.includes('closed');
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**mypipe.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'mypipe'
})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {


  transform(posts: any[], comment_status: any): any {

    return posts;

    console.log(comment_status);

    if(comment_status === 'all') {


    }
  }

}
```

Although all my change is happening via the component.ts at the moment, I'd like to set it up in the pipe.ts file, but simply getting that working has got me a little stumped. Any suggestions appreciated.

If it helps, App was setup using Angular 6 via Angular CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use template driven form way, make use of `[(ngModel)]` on select field & you'll no longer require that `(change)` method logic. So, update view code to:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="commentStatus">
   <option value="all" selected="selected">All</option>
   <option value="open">Open</option>
   <option value="closed">Closed</option>
</select>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let post of posts | myPipe:commentStatus">
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
      comment status: {{ post.comment_status }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then update your `transform` method from pipe class, so that it will take current value of `commentStatus` variable & then filters `posts` array. So, the pipe code can be like:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'myPipe'
})
export class MyPipePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(posts: any[], commentStatus: any): any {
    if(!commentStatus) {
      return posts;
    }
    if(commentStatus === 'all') {
      return posts;
    } else if(commentStatus === 'open' || commentStatus === 'closed') {
      let filterdPosts =  posts.filter((i) => {
      return i.comment_status == commentStatus;
      });
      return filterdPosts;
    }
  }

}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-7bdpde?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-pipe.pipe.ts)**

Comment: This was exactly what was stumping me! Perfect working example and works beautifully. Thank you!